# Change order of parameters in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following structure in my model :

```
geoLocation: {
  latitude: {
    type: Number
  },
  longitude: {
    type: Number
  }
}
```

I want to change the order to :

```
geoLocation: {
  longitude: {
    type: Number
  },
  latitude: {
    type: Number
  }
}
```

The problem is I have existing database in which data has been stored as :

```
"geoLocation" : {
    "latitude" : 23.0720184,
    "longitude" : 72.54213399999999
}
```

And I want to change order and want to save them as :

```
"geoLocation" : {
    "longitude" : 72.54213399999999,
    "latitude" : 23.0720184
}
```

I am using `$centerSphere` query of mongodb and it requires longitude as first argument. I tried to change order in model but it is not affecting the database.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is one way of doing it is by using [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). Please look for other better options too.

Using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) we can simply put the longitude at first, the mongodb code snippet is shown below

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([{
    $project:{
      _id:1, 
      "project all other fields as shown for _id":1,
      // Changing part
      "geoLocation.longitude":"$geoLocation.longitude", 
      "geoLocation.latitude":"geoLocation.latitude"
    }},
      // Overwriting the same collection with latitude and longitude changed
    {$out: "collection_name"}]);
```